# Unable to close serial port in nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-serialport

I'm using `node-serialport` available [here](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport). 
Open the port and reading works very well, however I am unable to close the port.

I use the following code for that:

```
myserialport.on('close', function (err) {
    console.log('port closed', err);  
});
```

The callback function is never executed (no console output).
Can anyone, please show me the way?

I would like to be able to close one port and open another if needed or just close the port if user changes the page.

Jan

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`.close()` method](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport#close-callback) to instruct the serial port to close:

```
myserialport.close(function (err) {
    console.log('port closed', err);
});
```

`.on('close')` allows you to [add the `function` as a listener](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_event_listener) of the `'close'` event. But, it will simply wait for the event to occur ([to be emitted](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_emit_event_arg1_arg2)) rather than instruct it to be done.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Now I understand my wrong thinking.
Is there a way to read the status of myserialport (is it open or closed) or should I set a flag, when opening/closing.
Another question when coming back to main page with a back arrow on the browser I need to refresh it (the page) manually. Is the a way to force a automatic refresh?

Comment: On Raspberry Pi3, When I am trying to connect to port again after calling `.close()`, I am getting 

> Serial port error: Error Resource temporarily unavailable Cannot lock port
Board detection failed for port: /dev/ttyUSB1

Any ideas?